# aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from

Tags: spring-mvc

here is the repository:

```
@Query(value = "select u.balance from User u where u.name=:name")
float toGetBalance(@Param("name") String name);
```

and here is the DAO interface:

```
boolean checkBalance(String userName, float totalPrice);
```

and here is the service

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public boolean checkBalance(String userName, float totalPrice) {

    if (userRepository.toGetBalance(userName) < totalPrice) {

        return false;

    } else {

        return true;

    }

}
```

and here is the error info:

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract float com.repository.UserRepository.toGetBalance(java.lang.String)
```

and the type of balance is float!

what's wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Change the signature of your repository to

```
@Query(value = "select u.balance from User u where u.name=:name")
Float toGetBalance(@Param("name") String name);
```

And it will simply return `null` if there is no such user in database with given `name`

Comment: Can I specify default value somehow?

Comment: @Klesun you could use Optional as a return value and do `getOrElse` on it, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/#repositories.nullability as of spring data 2.3.x

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that I know. I came here looking for a way to avoid `Optional` checks for queries like `COUNT()` that return `NULL` when no rows matched, but I guess JPA does not allow that.

Answer (score 1):

`@Query(value = "select u.balance from User u where u.name=:name")'
'Float toGetBalance(@Param("name") String name);`

This exception arise because name not exist  OR balance = NULL fpr the selected record in the table
So the query results no output. Spring JPA not able to bind the result with Return type Float.

`Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for: public abstract float com.repository.UserRepository.toGetBalance(java.lang.String)`